# Obtaining register address in STM32

Tags: stm32

I have a simple code for preserving and later using register address:

```
PWMChannel::PWMChannel(TIM_HandleTypeDef *timer, int channel)
{
    switch(channel)
    {
    case 1: ccr = &(timer->Instance->CCR1); break;
    case 2: ccr = &(timer->Instance->CCR2); break;
    case 3: ccr = &(timer->Instance->CCR3); break;
    case 4: ccr = &(timer->Instance->CCR4); break;
    case 5: ccr = &(timer->Instance->CCR5); break;
    case 6: ccr = &(timer->Instance->CCR6); break;
    }
}
```

Where ccr is a private class member: uint32_t *ccr = nullptr;
It is used to change duty cycle like this: *ccr = duty;

The code above worked just fine some time ago when I was using System Workbench. Recently I switched to CubeIDE. The only issue with porting project to new toolchain was with this member definition - it now required "volatile", so I changed it to: volatile uint32_t *ccr = nullptr;

However the code stopped working. The debugging shows that with channel parameter = 4 the ccr value becomes 0x40. Now, 0x40 is an offset of CCR4 within TIM_TypeDef structure (referenced by Instance), not an actual address of CCR4. If this is how it supposed to be then why it worked before and how do I change the code to make it work again?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured out what happened.

The object in question is statically initialized. Somehow this initialization happened after MX_TIM1_Init() call (in main.c) when I was building under System Workbench and before that call when I was building under CubeIDE. The "Instance" field is not yet initialized by the time constructor called, so it got wrong register address.

This is not the first time order of initialization bites me... :(

I already have most of the global objects either dynamically allocated or hidden behind functions in singleton pattern. Did not want to do it for this tiny helper object.

If somebody thinks this question is useless, tell me and I'll delete it.